# Couldn't determine the version of the native part of Reanimated , Cannot read property 'installCoreFunctions

Tags: react-native-reanimated, react-native-reanimated-v2

I am trying to integrate Reanimated 2.0 in iOS React Native project and getting the below error.

Once I import reanimated in my code I get this

> [Reanimated] Couldn't determine the version of the native part of Reanimated. Did you forget to re-build the app after upgrading react-native-reanimated?

> ERROR  TypeError: Cannot read property 'installCoreFunctions' of undefined, js engine: hermes

#### Package Info :

> ```
> "react": "17.0.2",
> ```

> ```
> "react-native": "0.67.5",
> ```

> ```
> "react-native-reanimated": "2.17.0" <- Tried many versions with same error
> ```

[x] Hermes is Enabled.

[x] Babel plugin is set for reanimate

[x] Done multiple time node_module clear and cache reset and react native clean project.

I tried many version of the reanimated

and followed the instructions from https://docs.swmansion.com/react-native-reanimated/docs/

[x] babel config Done

> The issue appeas once I add `import * as REA from 'react-native-reanimated';` If I remove this line the app working normally